# Transcode a live stream by FFmpeg & Redistribute it by VLC?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, vlc

Can someone point me to an URL concerning exactly this ?
I spent over half an hour and couldn't find this example..

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Even ​VLC can pick up the stream from ffmpeg, then redistribute it, acting as a server.

Thanks for your help!

Takashi